# Sql Server Bulk Insert during peak operations hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy, sqlperformance

I have a table in the DB which is usually quite frequently & concurrently queried, at peak somewhere close to 100 selects per second(guesstimating this based on analytics data). The row count in the table is gonna touch 200 million records soon. Continuous updates to single/individual rows, keep executing as well.

The data in this table is populated via a nightly job, intentionally off peak hours at 1 AM, in order to not impact the performance. The import size can sometimes go upto 1 million records. SqlBulkCopy is used, same as below example.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeID");
dt.Columns.Add("Name"); 

for (var i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)    
    dt.Rows.Add(i + 1, "Name " + i + 1);

using (var sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(_connectionString))
{
    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Employees";
    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

Recently got request by the source data system to perform the data pumping twice, once during day as well, effectively making us insert the data during peak hours.

Any suggestions, on how i can perform the SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy operation without impacting performance experienced by end users. Is there a scalable solution to this kind of scenario? Existing row count grows, import size grows & the end-user-base grows but still i can continue to perform such huge data pumping any time of the day.

Apologies, for not having much concrete data points to share, its a bit vague. Just wanted to get ideas how this is done by others, if anyone has an experience like this.

Comment: You could perhaps investigate partitioning and switching a staging table into your main table: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/

Comment: Thanks @SteveFord. Partitioning is more suited to the reporting kinda example you shared. In my cases the date ranges cant really be partitions. My data is user notifications. Need to fetch & serve newest and the oldest all together. And about the staging table way - can you please elaborate more? You mean we park the bulk data in a staging table first and then how to move it to the main table quickly and without impacting incoming selects?

Comment: Even with partitioning you can fetch newest & oldest data at the same time. The table is accessed just like any other table, it's just that the partitioned table is physically stored as separate tables. Any query of the table will get data in parallel from all partitions. The staging idea is that you load into a staging table that looks like the partitioned table and execute the switch statement. This makes the staging table a part of the table , this just changes the meta data.

Comment: Other alternatives are to experiment with Read Committed Snapshot Isolation, especially if your load process is the only process writing to the DB. With this setting (set at DB level) reads never block writes & writes never block reads. You may need to increase the size of TempDB but not necessarily if you still batch up the inserts.

Answer (score 0):

You can load data in small batches, so that, you are not generating big transaction and consuming lot of transaction log. After each batch, you can commit the transaction. You can use internal transaction approach, to make each batch as separate transaction.
[Read more on transactions and bulkcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/transaction-and-bulk-copy-operations)

```cs
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(
                       connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity |
                       SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
            {
                bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName =
                    "dbo.BulkCopyDemoMatchingColumns";

                // Write from the source to the destination.
                // This should fail with a duplicate key error
                // after some of the batches have been copied.
                try
                {
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
```

Additionally, there are some optimization tips available related to bulkcopy. You can try to leverage where possible: [Bulk Copy optimizations](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3095511/SQL-Server-Bulk-Copy-Optimization-Tips.htm)

Comment: Hey @Venkataraman. Thanks. Thats what we are already doing during the nightly job as well. Inserting using small batches. Are you saying that firing a huge number of small batches in quick fire, wouldnt have much impact during peak hours?

Comment: @techrookie, yes. small batches and committing them frequently, will avoid memory pressure and also transaction log pressure. We have tried earlier with small batches, which reduced the blocking on the main table.